# How to predict the values of a variable of an existing dataframe using line of best fit using python?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I don't know how to go about using line of best fit to predict the values of 2 variables in an existing dataframe.
For example, let's say column 'Year'  in a dataframe stopped at 2013 butI want my line of best fit to extend beyond 2050 to predict the values of 'Income' column (like the trend) plotting it using matplotlib.
I know I would probably use linregress() function from scipy.stats but I don't know how to predict it.
Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: I think you are looking for `extrapolation` you might use the `interp1d` function from scipy in combination with the argument `fill_value="extrapolate"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A linear regression will give you a slop and an intercept. For a given (unseen) `x` value (Year in your case), and a model, `res` built with `res = stats.linregress(x, y)`

```
res.intercept + res.slope*x
```

will tell you the `y` value (Income in your case)

Comment: Yes but how do I get to plot the line of best fit to predict the values of y-axis by extending the 'Year' column?